# Creating a for loop with a variable in batch

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, variables

I'm new to scripting in batch files.
Currently trying to get the hang of for loops.
I know how they should look like:

```
for /f %%i in (1, 1, 50) do (
    echo %%i
)
```

So that will print everything between 1 and 50, but I would like to know how to put a variable in the for loop like:

```
max=50
for /f %%i in (1, 1, max) do (
    echo %%i
)
```

But that just spits out an error.
Does anyone have another way of doing it (that works)?

Comment: Check the output of `for /?` again. You're looking for the `/L` flag, not the `/F` flag.

Comment: In the exact same way you use a variable in _any other place_ of a Batch file: enclosing the variable between percent signs: `%max%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set "max=50"
for /f %%i in (1; 1; %max%) do (
    echo %%i
)
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines...

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "max=50"
For /L %%A In (1,1,%max%) Do Echo %%A
```